# How do I output the preorder traversal of a tree given the inorder and postorder tranversal?

Tags: c++, data-structures, recursion, tree-traversal

Given the code for outputing the postorder traversal of a tree when I have the preorder and the inorder traversal in an integer array. How do I similarly get the preorder with the inorder and postorder array given?

```
void postorder( int preorder[], int prestart, int inorder[], int inostart, int length)
{ 
  if(length==0) return; //terminating condition
  int i;
  for(i=inostart; i<inostart+length; i++)
    if(preorder[prestart]==inorder[i])//break when found root in inorder array
      break;
  postorder(preorder, prestart+1, inorder, inostart, i-inostart);
  postorder(preorder, prestart+i-inostart+1, inorder, i+1, length-i+inostart-1);
  cout<<preorder[prestart]<<" ";
}
```

Here is the prototype for preorder()

void preorder( int inorderorder[], int inostart, int postorder[], int poststart, int length)

to use postorder() it will be

```
int preorder[6]={6,4,1,5,8,9};
int inorder[6]={1,4,5,6,8,9};
postorder( preorder,0,inorder,0,6);
```

out put will be

```
1 5 4 9 8 6
```

below is the incorrect code for print_preorder(), still not working below

```
void print_preorder( int inorder[], int inostart, int postorder[], int poststart, int length)
    {
      if(length==0) return; //terminating condition
      int i;
      for(i=inostart; i<inostart+length; i++)
        if(postorder[poststart+length-1]==inorder[i])
          break; 
      cout<<postorder[poststart+length-1]<<" ";
      print_preorder(inorder, inostart , postorder, poststart, i-inostart);
      print_preorder(inorder, inostart+i-poststart+1, postorder, i+1, length-i+inostart-1);
    }
```

Comment: it makes sense how to do the postorder, but figuring out how torecursively call the print_preoder is really tripping me.

Comment: @user342580 : i gave you a few more hints in my answer... tricky problem, but you probably _won't_ be able to do it without understanding the algorithm on paper first.

Comment: I changed it, I got the first recursive call correct, but my change to the second one is causing an infinite loop,and I still can't figure out why. I guess I'll just hope I get partial credit on this extra credit problem. Thanks though, you were very helpful.

Comment: @user342580:  I'd suggest printing the length and inputs (and the resulting arrays) at the top of the function, then see how it matches against the call stack I drew.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a few hints:

- The last element in the `postorder` subarray is your new `preorder` root.
- The `inorder` array can be split in two on either side of the new `preorder` root.
- You can call recursively call the `print_preorder` function on those two `inorder` subarrays.
- When calling the `print_preorder` function, the `inorder` and `postorder` arrays will be the same size.
- You have an out-of-bounds array access: `postorder[poststart+length]` is past the end of the array.  To get the last element, you want `postorder[poststart+length-1]`
- Your first recursive `print_preorder` function chooses the wrong length.  Remember that `length` is the length of the subarray, but `inostart` is the absolute position within the `inorder` array.  Your function will probably call with a negative `length`.
- Your second recursive function is pretty far off for translating the bounds and length.  It'll probably help to draw it on paper and trace your algorithm.

It may help to draw the tree:

```
     6
   /   \
  4     8
 / \     \
1   5     9
```

Then write out the three traversals:

```
// index:         0 1 2 3 4 5
int postorder[6]={1,5,4,9,8,6};
int inorder[6]=  {1,4,5,6,8,9};
int preorder[6]= {6,4,1,5,8,9};
```

Now, put down the computer, get out a pen & paper and *think* about the problem :)

Imagine this call stack (the new root is printed on the left):

```
6 print_preorder(len=6, in=[1 4 5 6 8 9], post=[1 5 4 9 8 6])
4 |-> print_preorder(len=3, in=[1 4 5], post=[1 5 4])
1 |   |-> print_preorder(len=1, in=[1], post=[1])
  |   |   |-> print_preorder(len=0, in=[], post=[])
  |   |   |-> print_preorder(len=0, in=[], post=[])
5 |   |-> print_preorder(len=1, in=[5], post=[5])
  |       |-> print_preorder(len=0, in=[], post=[])
  |       |-> print_preorder(len=0, in=[], post=[])
8 |-> print_preorder(len=2, in=[8 9], post=[9 8])
      |-> print_preorder(len=0, in=[], post=[])
9     |-> print_preorder(len=1, in=[9], post=[9])
          |-> print_preorder(len=0, in=[], post=[])
          |-> print_preorder(len=0, in=[], post=[])
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 4):

1. The last element in post order will be the root of the tree.
2. After that we will look in Inorder array to determine the position of the root. left side of the array is left sub tree and right side is right sub tree.
3. By using that index we shall determine the element in left which is the root.
4. similarly we do for the right sub tree, The main idea is we determine the indexes of left sub tree and right sub tree by looking in inorder array. hope i was clear..

   ```
   public static void printpreorder(char []inorder,int i_start,int i_end,char[] postorder,int p_start,int p_end)
   {
     if(i_start > i_end || p_start > p_end)
            return ; 
     char root = postorder[p_end];
     System.out.print(root);
     System.out.print("(");
       int k=0;
         for(int i=0; i< inorder.length; i++){
             if(inorder[i]==root){
               k = i;
               break;
             }
         }
     printpreorder(inorder, i_start, k-1, postorder, p_start, p_start+k-(i_start+1));
     System.out.print(")(");
     printpreorder(inorder, k+1, i_end, postorder, p_start+k-i_start, p_end-1);
     System.out.print(")");    
   }
   ```

This was hommework for me. Thanks to @Stephen for a good answer

Comment: Hi, WannaBe, it's better if you explain *why* your code solves the problem. See [answer].

Comment: It was just a heads up ;) Code only answers are really poor and don't teach anything.